# Probability of choosing the same number from two different ranges

Tags: probability

I am working on some probabilities and am trying to figure out how to get the probability of two people picking the same number when given two different ranges.

For example:

```
 Person A: Can choose a number from [0,14]
 Person B: Can choose a number from [0, 6]
```

Is the probability that they pick the same number just 1/15 * 1/7?

Comment: The chosen numbers should be integer?

Comment: Person $A$ has $15 $options (assuming u mean $\{0,1,...,14\}$ and $\{0,1,...,6\}$, while person $B$: $7$ options. Note that person $B$ can choose anything and it all is left for person $A$ to pick exactly the same number.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac1{15}\cdot\frac17$ is the probability that they both pick, say, the number $3$. If you don't care about the specific number, but rather just that they pick the same, then note that no matter what $B$ picks, there is a $\frac1{15}$ probability that A picks the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, because if A picks anything above $6$, then there is a $0$ probability that $B$ picks the same, rather than $\frac{1}{7}$

Also, using $\frac{1}{15}$ would make sense if there is a specific number that $A$ has to pick in order to get a match (e.g. $4$) .. but of course there are *several* numbers $A$ can pick that can lead to a match.

Indeed, with $7$ out of $15$ possible numbers that $A$ can pick to possibly get a match, and with a chance of $1$ out of $7$ for $B$ to match that number, you get:
 $\frac{7}{15} \cdot \frac{1}{7}=\frac{1}{15}$